# ArrayList of Objects of different classes that belong to a superclass?

Tags: java, arraylist

In the following code what should be put between '<' and '>' so that I will be able to add new object of each subclass of Animal superclass ?

```
package animal;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal createAnimals = new Animal();
        createAnimals.userInputHandle();

        ArrayList <> animalList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        animalList.add(new Dog);

    }

    private String userInputHandle(){

        String userInput;
        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Select animal from the "
                + "following list"
                + "\n1.Dog\n2.Cat\n3.Snake\n4.Frog"
                + "\n5.Human\n6.Shark\n7.Sea Gulls");
        userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

    return userInput;}
}

class Fish extends Animal{




}
class Amphibians extends Animal{

}
class Reptiles extends Animal{}
class Birds extends Animal{}
```

So that I will make a method in Animal class and override it for each subclasses. For example for Amphibians--> Frog belongs to amphibian class and so on.

Comment: it will be 'Animal' only, since u will derive rest of the class from 'Animal' Class

Answer (score 3):

```
// this will work fine as 'Animal' will be base class for other class
ArrayList <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>(); 
//
animalList.add(new Reptiles());
animalList.add(new Birds());
animalList.add(new Amphibians());
```

Comment: this solved it. It feels so stupid not being able to figure out that one too. Thanks.

Comment: yw most welcome, feel free to marked the question as solved, as this will help other learners too!

Comment: There is nuthing like stupidity in world of progamming, everything is an experience, and i have been on the same path at some point in my life :P!

Answer (score 2):

If you make the declaration

```
ArrayList <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

then you'll be able to add any subclass of Animal to it.

Answer (score 1):

Make your declaration on your ArrayList like this.

```
ArrayList <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

To add subclasses of Animal.

```
animalList.add(new Monkey());
animalList.add(new Donkey());
```

and etc.

If you are using Java SE7 another way to instantiate a Generic(in your case an ArrayList) is to use a limited type inference like this.

```
ArrayList <Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
```